# Cheating on tests, when all students are doing it

Tags: emes-truth-honesty

This seems to be a common issue in the Corona era when tests are administered remotely. The teachers have no way of enforcing the students not to discuss the questions among themselves or to look up answers.

It seems that many students are "cheating"(or at least for purposes of this question let's make that assumption). The honest ones end up losing because they can no longer benefit from a curve and their class standing is hurt. If cheating is rampant, does that make it permissible for all students? Would it make a difference if the teachers are aware of what is happening?

(Looking for a halachic answer)

Comment: Just because 'everyone is doing it', does not negate the ethical and moral nature of something. Would you kill someone if 'everyone is doing it'?

Comment: @Dov The question is whether or not it is ethical. Sometimes a rule is judged by its ability to be enforced. Kind of like jay walking. This will especially be true if the school is aware of it.

Comment: I think they(students) will eventually get caught out when they apply for a job which they have cheated because they wrote extensively on and then when it comes to it they can’t do it. The teachers know it and they can scream and shout it but nobody cares until it’s too late.

Comment: @DanielRoss what if this is for an elective that has no bearing on their future?

Comment: @Mark Everything has a bearing on the future. If the person thinks it’s ok to cheat in this exam for example middle school that an employer wouldn’t need see then why not for this exam which makes or breaks a person future. If you do it once and got away with it then you can do it again until you get caught. At the end of the day you’re only lying to yourself.

Comment: Have you considered having them ask the teacher what they should do? As long as you get permission from the teacher, it's not cheating

Comment: There is an Igros Moshe about cheating, [אגרות משה - חלק ז](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/921) Siman 30 (page 241)

Comment: אמר רבי אלעזר הכל נפרע בידי שליח חוץ מאונאה -- Rabbi Elazar said: "All sinners are punished through a messenger, except the cheater [who is punished by God Himself]. [Ein Yaakov (Glick) on Bava Metzia 4:8]